# How do i make a bot from discord.py play music in my voice chat?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

I have the youtube module installed. When I say !play_song Like a g6, it comes up with the error as its not connected in the voice chat but it is.

```
@bot.command(name='play_song', help='To play song')
async def play(ctx,url):
    try :
        server = ctx.message.guild
        voice_channel = server.voice_client

        async with ctx.typing():
            filename = await YTDLSource.from_url(url, loop=bot.loop)
            voice_channel.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(executable="ffmpeg.exe", source=filename))
        await ctx.send('**Now playing:** {}'.format(filename))
    except:
        await ctx.send("The bot is not connected to a voice channel.")
```

Comment: You are completely silencing all errors with your unconditional `try` / `except`.

Comment: What will it look like then?

Comment: Cause i took them out and still no music

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Idk how to solve that either, but if u need a play music command from yt, you can use my code here, just change the description and the command name.

```html
@client.command()
async def playyt(ctx, url):
    song_there = os.path.isfile("song.mp3")
    try:
        if song_there:
            os.remove("song.mp3")
    except PermissionError:
        em8 = discord.Embed(title = "Music Is Currently Playing", description = 'Please wait for the current playing music to end or use %leave <:_Paimon6:827074349450133524>.\nMusic provided by {ctx.author.mention} <:_Paimon6:827074349450133524>',color = ctx.author.color)
        await ctx.send(embed = em8)
        return

    voiceChannel = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.voice_channels)
    await voiceChannel.connect()
    voice = discord.utils.get(client.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)
    em6 = discord.Embed(title = "Downloading Youtube Music", description = f'{url}\n\nPlease wait for paimon to setup the music you provide.\nMusic provided by {ctx.author.mention} <:_Paimon6:827074349450133524>',color = ctx.author.color)
    await ctx.send(embed = em6, delete_after = 2)
    await ctx.message.delete()

    ydl_opts = {
        'format': 'bestaudio/best',
        'postprocessors': [{
            'key': 'FFmpegExtractAudio',
            'preferredcodec': 'mp3',
            'preferredquality': '196',
        }],
    }
    with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
        ydl.download([url])
    for file in os.listdir("./"):
        if file.endswith(".mp3"):
            os.rename(file, "song.mp3")
    voice.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio("song.mp3"))
    em1 = discord.Embed(title = "Now Listening Youtube Music", description = f'{url}\n\nPlease use %leave first to change music.\nMusic provided by {ctx.author.mention} <:_Paimon6:827074349450133524>',color = ctx.author.color)

    videoID = url.split("watch?v=")[1].split("&")[0]

    em1.set_thumbnail(url = f'https://img.youtube.com/vi/{videoID}/default.jpg'.format(videoID = videoID))
    await ctx.send(embed = em1)
```

This command will download a music directly from youtube using yt_dl and then the downloaded music is stored in your bot directory, and after finish downloading, your bot will process the song by converting the downloaded file into mp3, just wait for a while, and its automatically played. This command can only play 1 song, you need to disconnect the bot from vc in order to play another music.